# Change the format of the MeetingRequest when creating an Appointment using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568699/removing-ews-appointment-body-text), [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/7d50b1c3-a53a-48b5-90e1-2ed127b5d281/removing-ews-appointment-body-text?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/70b6e494-9395-415d-9151-d21cd8b4f4af/getting-extra-content-in-body-of-outlook-appointment-item-created-by-using-appointment-class?forum=outlookdev), **somebody** prepends some undesired & redundant information (*when-text*, *where-text*) to a meeting request body.

That is, when you create a *new appointment (meeting)* using the *EWS Managed API* and execute the **service.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy)** operation, a mail message whose body contains that redundant information (*when*, *where*) is saved in the *Sent Items* folder. On the other hand, upon creating an appointment in Outlook, the body of the mail message is fine.

Do you have any ideas concerning this issue - how could it be avoided?

Is it possible to save an appointment using **service.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll)** and create a **"clean"** *MeetingRequest* item afterwards - to be saved in the *Sent Items* folder?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to suppress the when and where text in EWS. It's purpose is to support non-calendar-capable email clients where only the body text is visible. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/14e034da-9833-465e-ac48-207e465466bf/time-added-to-appointment-body-in-recipient-calendar?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment