# How to read emails message BodyText through EWS? C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I would like to get all messages.BodyText in my email. I have already some code, tried many things, but didn't catch what really will work.

My code:

```
ExchangeService service;

        service = new ExchangeService
        {
            Credentials = new WebCredentials("mail.com", @"password")
        };

        
        List<String> items = new List<String>();
        // This is the office365 webservice URL
        service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        ItemView view = new ItemView(50);

          FindItemsResults<Item> Items = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view); // line 34
        // 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' / on line 34

        foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            if (item is EmailMessage)
            {
                item.Load();
                string subject = item.Subject;
                string mailMessage = item.Body;
            }
            items.Add(item.TextBody); // line 44
            //You must load or assign this property before you can read its value / on line 44
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

When I'm trying to run my code, then I got two errors:

1. You must load or assign this property before you can read its value / on line 44
2. 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' / on line 34

The second error is working from time to time, I'm not sure what is wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Line numbers on your example code would help, or markers to show which error relates to which line.

Comment: My guess is on line 34 the WellKnownFolderName value is not defined and that is causing it not to load the items properly further on.

Comment: @EricConklin Yeah, but it's working from time to time and when it's working normally, then line 44 still does not work.

Comment: In that case you are probably not loading it. You have a conditional for if item is EmailMessage a few lines before you access the TextBody property. There are probably a few items in your collection that are not EmailMessages and hence are not loaded on line 44 causing this error. I would load all the EmailMessages before you access their properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Text body of the message then you need to use a propertyset that will specifically request that. A message may not have a Text body so in that instance the Exchange store will do an on the fly conversion what you code should look like is

```
            PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
        {
            RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text
        };         

        foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            if (item is EmailMessage)
            {
                item.Load(psPropSet);
                string subject = item.Subject;
                string mailMessage = item.Body;
            }
            items.Add(item.TextBody); 
        }
```

Keep in mind this will make a call to the Exchange server every time you call Load which is really inefficient and done on a large scale will mean you code with be throttled. This can be batched using LoadPropertiesForItems in EWS eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/614111/processing-120k-emails-takes-more-than-a-day-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the load method before attempting to assign a value.

In your code here:

```
foreach (Item item in Items)
        {
            if (item is EmailMessage)
            {
                item.Load();
                string subject = item.Subject;
                string mailMessage = item.Body;
            }
            items.Add(item.TextBody); // line 44
            //You must load or assign this property before you can read its value / on line 44
        }
```

You are checking if an item is EmailMessage. There may be some in the list that are not an EmailMessage which would cause them to be accessed before using the Load method.

You could try putting the item load outside of the conditional and that would most likely fix the issue.

Please see this question here:
[Error when I try to read/update the .Body of a Task via EWS Managed API - "You must load or assign this property before you can read its value."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304157/error-when-i-try-to-read-update-the-body-of-a-task-via-ews-managed-api-you-m)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately, I also tried without if statement. It's still saying that: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value. And I also read that post, but didn't get any idea how to fix it.